# GrahicsDevice and JOptionPane Issue

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, joptionpane

When I click the button, the application which is set to full screen will go to taskbar/minimized, so I need to click it first in the taskbar before seeing the `JOptionPane` that I triggered. What do you think is the problem with this? I'd like it to run smoothly without being minimized or going to taskbar.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Sample");
        GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
        device.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600, 32, 60)); 
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setText("Btn");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(btn);
        frame.add(panel);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Sample");
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried a `JDialog` instead of `JOptionPane`?

Comment: Thanks. :) Anyway, if there will be a good answer to my question why not accept it. :)

Comment: I just tried it with `JDialog`, they have the same output.

Comment: 1) Never call `setVisible(true)` on `JFrame` until all components have been added. 2) Why the throw `UnsupportedOperationException`?

Answer (score 1):

One workaround here would be to use

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

instead of

```
device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
```

Also as mentioned in the comments, `setVisible(true)` should appear when all the components have been added.

Comment: The application has a fixed size of 800x600. It cant be extended the state. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The only work around I can think of is to add a `WindowAdpater` to `JFrame` which will override `windowIconified(..)`. There is also a `boolean` used as a flag for the program to know when the window is iconified due to `JOptionPane` being shown.

Its really hacky though and only after a few screen flashes do we see the `JOptionPane` and `JFrame` working together nicely.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    private static boolean programmatic = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setTitle("Sample");
                GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
                device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
                device.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600, 32, 60));

                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent we) {
                        //super.windowIconified(we);
                        if (programmatic) {
                            programmatic = false;
                            frame.setState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                        }
                    }
                });

                JButton btn = new JButton();
                btn.setText("Btn");
                final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

                panel.add(btn);
                frame.add(panel);

                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        programmatic = true;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Sample");
                    }
                });
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And thinking about it more, `JDialog` also reproduces results, I think its due to the [modality](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) of `JOptionPane`s and `JDialog`s. Maybe using `JDialog` and setting the modality would do the trick.

Comment: Nice, but I am working on full screen. I'd like it to be running smoothly without flashes. Thanks.

Comment: @jong unfortunately I do not think it can be done..... I may be mistaken but I've tried the whole night to no avail, which includes googling many have the same problem but no solution.... If anything is try using a jpanel and styling as necessary

Comment: Thank you David Kroukamp. Is there a way to up your reputation?

Comment: @Jong pleasure, and to increase or decrease a persons reputation simply click the up arrow or down arrow respectively, the tick mark next to posts is used to mark it as the answer. Hope that helps

Comment: I only have 10 reputation, it needs 15 to tick that mark button.

Comment: @Jong not a problem come back when you do... but I see you have [reposted the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018892/joptionpane-and-graphicsdevice-not-working-together). So is this really the answer you want? I think not, you are in no way obligated to mark this as the answer regardless of whether it is or isnt, also why ask duplicate questions?