# JOptionPane showing outside JFrame with GraphicsDevice

Tags: java, swing, awt, fullscreen, joptionpane

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Frame");
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
        device.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600, 32, 60));
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setText("Button");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(btn);
        frame.add(panel);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "JOptionPane");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I click the button, the application which is set to full screen will go to taskbar/minimized, so I need to click it first in the taskbar before seeing the JOptionPane that I triggered. What do you think is the problem with this? I'd like it to run smoothly without being minimized or going to taskbar. Looking forward for your answers. Thanks in advance. Or is there any other alternative to this?

Comment: 1 thing no need for setVisible(true) on Jframe as `setFullScreenWindow(frame);` will set the frame to visible if it is not. with that said i'd also move this call too after all components are added to JFrame not that ot fixes the problem, but lessens the likelyhood of possible causes

Comment: @DavidKroukamp, I deleted my older questions. Its just that I want it to be answered and not being left over.

Comment: @Jong I was about to suggest deleting older questions. In that case my mistake. I too would like the solution or atlesst what could be at fault. Plus 1

Comment: @Jong here is a duplicate which hasnt been deleted.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014523/grahicsdevice-and-joptionpane-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(frame.getContentPane(), "JOptionPane");
```

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?  Did you solve the problem with that code from my answer?  Seems unlikely since that code fails here.  As such this seems to be 'not an answer', but I have no idea what you thought it would be.

Comment: Huh.  I failed to notice the **Internal** part of that code line.  So it is not the same code I showed.  OK - you might as well acept your answer.  Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 6):

That code works for me, though you might try this variant with 2 changes.

1. It creates and shows the GUI on the EDT.
2. It uses the content pane of the frame as the parent of the `JOptionPane`

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setTitle("Frame");
                frame.setSize(800, 600);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
                device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
                device.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600, 32, 60));
                frame.setVisible(true);

                JButton btn = new JButton();
                btn.setText("Button");
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();

                panel.add(btn);
                frame.add(panel);

                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "JOptionPane");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame.getContentPane(), "JOptionPane");
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

### Update

When I add the following lines to the beginning of the source seen above..

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));
```

..the output & result is as follows.

#### Running in 1.7

**Result:**  Failure as described in the question.

```
1.7.0_09
23.5-b02
```

#### Running in 1.6

**Result:**  Success with no unusual artifacts or behavior.

```
1.6.0
1.6.0-b105
```

### Analysis

Note that other results from comments suggest the behavior changed some time between that early 1.6 version, and 1.6.0_25.  It seems like a regression bug. The OP should check the [bug database](http://bugs.sun.com/) & if nothing likely shows up, lodge a new report.

Comment: Why is it in mine, it doesn't. What do you mean working? You mean it runs smoothly without flashes?

Comment: *"so I need to click it first in the taskbar before seeing the JOptionPane that I triggered"* I did not need to click first.

Comment: So you mean, upon clicking the button the `JOptionPane` pop outs already?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I too am surprised this works, on my OS (windows 7 x64 Java7u10) when I click the button the fulscreen JFrame is minimized and no JOptionPane is shown (It is there but behind other windows etc and the fullscreen frame has been minimized) only once the app is pressed on taskbar to bring it back to focus does the JoptionPane show perfectly on top of fullscreen JFrame

Comment: @DavidKroukamp  I was initially testing using 1.6, it fails as described in 1.7.  Seems like a regression bug.  -- The OP should check the [bug database](http://bugs.sun.com/) & if nothing likely shows up, lodge a new report.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp, I kept on regulating the rulo. Its just that im too desperate about it. I need it for my academic requirement.

Comment: @AndrewThompson just as I thought it must be as last answer on the OPs question said it worked and he was using Java 6. +1 to comment and answer in hopes you will edit your answer to reflect your comment, as there is no bug I can find that has been lodged and many others on  the net have suffered similar problems and this might be the place where the solution/the reason is debuted, until bug is submitted:)

Comment: @Jong seems you have the answer, what is your java version if 1.7 seems you must use Java 6 (as to exact version Im not sure but Oracle right now suggest Java6u38 as the best as many security holes existed before that)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp, Im using version 1.6.0_25.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp  Question edited along the lines you suggest, with more specific information re. versions used locally.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, do you think in Java6u38 will run smoothly?

Comment: Given it is broken in 1.6.0_25 & 1.7, I suspect 'no'.

Comment: @Jong use the version Andrew used which produced correct results, I just suggest Java6u38 as the best one (if possible which now we know it is not)

Comment: I think its better to use the newer versions. Im thinking of other ways like modal JFrame as an alternative to JOptionPane, what do you think?

Comment: @David It seems the OP has settled on a work-around.  See their answer for details.